# Does Django pick template changes when DEBUG=False? Yes, but HOW?

Tags: django, django-templates

Yes it does! I just tested within an Nginx/gunicorn setup. Sub-questions:

1. How does it notice the change in the template(s)?
2. Does performance suffer in any way because of this "feature"?
3. Can this "feature" be disabled/re-enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not cache the loading of templates by default.  Because they are not cached, they get loaded from disk every time they are rendered and that is why you'll see template changes without reloading the application.

If you're interested in caching the template loading process to improve performance (it will help a lot if you are rendering a number of different templates per request), take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308996/does-djangos-render-to-response-cache-unrendered-templates-or-load-from-disk-ev).